# Split lines by minimum number of overlapping/shared vertices

Tags: qgis, splitting, linestring, vertices

I have a line layer converted from a polygon layer, and I do not know how to split the lines at vertices which overlap vertices of at least 2 other features. In the image below, I want to split the line (in yellow) at vertices overlapping/shared with 2 or more other adjacent features (in blue circles):

[image: Split line by minimum number of overlapping vertices]

I tried using the algorithms `Explode lines` and `v.split.vert` but it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the use of 'native:saveselectedfeatures' and 'saga:splitlinesatpoints' methods of Processing Toolbox in QGIS. For testing my approach, I digitized only two line features from your image (arbitrarily projected with EPSG:32612) as follows (selected feature in yellow and second feature in green). At the same image, it can also be observed cut points very close (< 1 m) to selected line.

[image]

After running 'native:saveselectedfeatures', resulting layer was produced as expected.

[image]

Afterward, I ran 'saga:splitlinesatpoints' method with following parameters (epsilon 1 m).

[image]

Result was as expected after removing first feature in resulting layer.

[image]